# Screen reader reading previous page in chrome after successful navigation in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, react-router-dom, nvda

The problem:

The screen reader **NVDA** reads the **previous** page even after successful navigation to the next page.
I am using **react-router-dom** for navigation and when I use **history.push()** command to navigate to the next page, it still reads the text from the previous page in NVDA screen reader although that page is not visible on the screen and this issue is only replicable in **google chrome browser**.

I do not know for sure but I noticed this after a recent update of multiple packages.

Please note that this only happens when I am using **push** command and when using **Links** of react-router-dom it is working as expected and it also works fine in Mozilla Browser

Here are the versions used:

React: "^16.8.4",

react-dom: "^16.8.4",

react-router-dom: "^4.3.1",

react-scripts: "^3.4.0",

google chrome: Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit),

NVDA (Screen Reader): 2019.2.1

Expected result: **NVDA** screen reader should Only read the current page after navigating to a certain page and should not read the text/button(or any elements) of the previous page after navigating away.

Actual Result: **NVDA** screen reader reads the previous page elements after navigation in **Google Chrome.**

Thank you for Helping